# Javascript: escape %d in string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got the following code in Node.js:

```
var str = '',
    ch;

for(/*standard for loop*/){
 // some code ...

 ch = '%' + buffer[i].toString(16);

 str += ch;
}
```

Now when `buffer[i].toString(16)` returns, let's say `d6`, resulting string doesn't contain `%d6`, but `NaN6` instead.

Now I know %d is used in C's sprinf, but afaik JavaScript nor Node has sprintf or equivalent function.

I need `%d6` in my string, so what can I do to prevent JS from automatically converting `%d` (and others, like `%f`) to NaN?

Comment: NaN stands for not a number.  It usually happens when you try to apply numerical functions to strings.

Comment: he is probably using toString() for own purposes, because toString() should be without parameters (16). Use my solution.

Comment: the argument 16 means he wants a hex number returned: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp

Comment: @stephen: exactly. It's not my own method.

Comment: I was unaware of that parameter, as it is very recent: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node's console.log() - the standard function for outputting - that I was using to print out the result behaves as printf and that is actually documented (http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/stdio.html#console.log). Silly me, thanks averyone for leding me to the solution.

sys.puts() prints the expected string.

Comment: you can also escape the `%` signs then by doubling them, or inserting the raw string: `console.log("these %% signs are interpretted, that one %s is inserted.", "%")`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use toString method for your own purproses, because JS already has own function with that name.

1. Update firefox to newest version. Also make sure you are using firefox.
2. I tested and your solution should work. Please alert() everything.

What is the output of:

```
ch = '%' + buffer[i].toString(16);
alert(ch);
alert(buffer[i]);
alert(buffer[i].toString(16));
```

Comment: Docs say otherwise: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString

toString() is okay, it returns the right string, and everything works fine if I do not concatenate it to the % sign. I've only encountered this problem when toString() returns string with first char 'd' or 'f'. With other chars (a, b, ...) it works just fine.

Comment: If so, have you debuged what is the value of: buffer[i]

Comment: Ascii 223 char, and toString() returns hexadecimal string 'df'. It gets 'converted' to NaN after doing contatenation with '%'.

Comment: I tested everything in console, so there are 3 options.

Comment: i'm running node.js which is running chrome's v8. Found out what the problem was, posted it in the answers. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in the code you pasted, if we do a quick test:

```
function test()
{
  var stuff = 214;
  var str = '', ch;

  ch = '%' + stuff.toString(16);
  alert(ch);
}
```

we see that what we want to be returned is in fact returned (%d6).

NaN stands for not a number, are you sure what is in your buffer array is a number? Are you calling any other methods/functions on ch?

Comment: well running the code in chrome debugger worked well. Actually afterall the problem lies within node's console.log, which behaves as printf. Stupid me.